# Exception raised during rendering: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match

Tags: android, photoshop

I was trying to incorporate a image as a splash page for my android app. This image was created by one of my friends using photoshop. When I try to use this image as a background for my android application it says : **"Exception raised during rendering: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match"** . Is there a way to fix this image non programatically, i.e. using photoshop or any other tools. If not is there any thing which can be done programatically.

Comment: happen to me, no solution till now! :(, will update if i get any

Answer (score 1):

This most probably is due to `Bit Depth` Field may be or any other image related properties because of which `Eclipse IDE/ ADT` is not able to render the image into `ImageView`.

The work around i use to convert same image into other format, In my case image was `image.jpg` which I converted to `image.png` using the Online Image Editor - [Pixlr Editor](http://pixlr.com/editor/)

Hope this helps!!